# Scikit-learn minmaxscaler error

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I'm trying to normalize my data. Currently my approach to get data is just counting some sequences. I'd like to run SVM on these data, but I found in scikit-learn documentation recommendation to scale data to interval [-1,1] or [0,1]. They recommend to use MinMaxScaler. I tried to use it, but it just doesn't work. I am getting this error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:332: 
UserWarning: MinMaxScaler assumes floating point values as input, got |S27
  "got %s" % (estimator, X.dtype))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Matej/PycharmProjects/Diploma/get_viral_sequence.py", line 455, in <module>
    min_max_scaler.fit_transform(np.asarray(matrix[1:, :len(sequence_attributes)]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 426, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 204, in fit
    data_min = np.min(X, axis=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2214, in amin
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 21, in _amin
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I tried to save data without casting (list_temp.count(attr)), with converting it to numpy.int32 and converting it to numpy.float32, it is all the time the same result.

Shape of array is `(44, 16384)`.

Comment: How do you obtain `X` and what's `type(X)` and `X.dtype`?

Comment: @Barmaley.exe type(X) `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>` and X.dtype is `|S27` and I don't know why...

Comment: This `|S27` doesn't look like a valid type to me. What if you do `X = X.astype(numpy.float32)` before?

Comment: I think I found an error - first row of my array were attributes (strings). I guess that is why it wasn't working.